# Command line command to copy file with directory

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a file which is in folder structure like this `E:\project\b\c\d\e\my.js` I need to copy this file to another folder along with  it's directory structure

e.g. I want to copy this file in `E:\project\patch`. So the command should do copy in such a way that when I run it the file should be at `E:\project\patch\b\c\d\e\my.js`. I can not copy folder `b` directly to the folder `patch` using file explorer cause `b` has so many other sub folders and files. I don't want to copy those.

Currently I am doing creating folder manually and copying the file. But I pretty much sure there will a command for this.

Comment: How many such files do you have to copy from different paths?

Comment: only one file. Currently what I am doing is creating directory structure using `mkdir path\to\file` then copy the file manually.

Comment: I'm @ work and cannot work out the full answer. When I searched - it looks like linux has a [command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265702/how-to-get-full-path-of-a-file?answertab=votes#tab-top) called `readlink`. You have to find the equivalent for it in [Windows](www.bryanpendleton.blogspot.com/2010/07/windows-and-file-links.html) This will give you the complete path. Once it is a text, you can pick what you need and use `mkdir` command to create the directory and copy the file name using another command.

Comment: Thanks for sharing link. I'll go through it and see what I can do... You can workout the full answer later, it's not urgent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in windows.

> Copy a file:
>
> > echo F| XCOPY C:\utils\MyFile.txt D:\Backup\CopyFile.txt
>
> Copy a folder:
>
> > XCOPY C:\utils D:\Backup\utils /i
>
> Copy a folder including all subfolders.
>
> > XCOPY C:\utils* D:\Backup\utils /s /i

Answer (score 0):

Use robocopy command

> Copy a directory including sub directories and the files in sub
>   directories

```
Robocopy /S D:\dir1\data E:\backup\data
```

> This command does not copy empty directories. To copy them, you need
>   to add /E switch.

```
Robocopy /S /E  D:\dir1\data E:\backup\data
```

The syntax is `robocopy [options] [source] [destination]`

Comment: The OP does not want the other files in the subdirectories to be copied. Will robocopy do that?

Comment: There is a /MIR switch specifies that Robocopy should mirror the source directory and the destination directory. Note that this will delete files at the destination if they were deleted at the source.

Comment: OP can experiment with the commands and see... but please create a backup:)

Comment: OP you can read more about the available switches here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A way to do that is store the path into a variable and then use it with the new destination.

Use something like:

`SET MY_PATH_SRC=E:\project\b\c\d\e\`

and

`SET MY_PATH_DST=E:\project\patch\b\c\d\e\`

then just copy using the new strings as base path.

Example:

```
copy MY_PATH_SRC\my.js MY_PATH_DST\my.js
```